# Can I use class without constructor?

Tags: dart

I am learning Dart. I did not found any answer for my question in docs.
Can I create and use class without constructor, or I can get some problem with it later?

```
class MyClass {
  String name;
  int age;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an use a class with no *explicit* constructor.

If you do not write any constructor, you will be given a default constructor of `MyClass() : super();`. That only works if

- Your class has no final fields without initializer expressions.
- Your superclass has an unnamed generative constructor which can be called with no arguments (which `Object` satisfies.)

It means that your get a *public* generative constructor, which allows others to extend your class. If you want to prevent that, you can change that to a public factory/private generative constructor pair:

```dart
  factory C() => C._();
  C._();
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you don’t have to use a constructor in your class, but that takes away your ability to create an immutable class with final fields plus you can’t set your values instantly. There will always be a default constructor for your class without you defining it. With your current code you’d have to do something like

```dart
final myVar = MyClass();
myVar.name = "John";
myVar.age = 24;
```